# how can i solve sql query of employee and dependent table

Tags: mysql

```
create table EMPLOYEE (Fname varchar(15), Minit char, Lname varchar(15), Ssn int PRIMARY KEY, Bdate date, Address varchar(31), Sex char, Salary int, Super_ssn int, Dno int);

create table DEPENDENT (Essn int , Dependent_name varchar(15) , Sex char, Bdate date, Relationship varchar(15), PRIMARY KEY(Essn,Dependent_name));
```

Count the number of dependents of each sex belonging to each male employee. Display lname, ssn, count of dependents, and sex of dependent. Order by lname.

my sql query is below:

```
CREATE VIEW R1 AS
SELECT Lname as 'LAST NAME', Ssn
FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE SEX='M';
SELECT * FROM R1;

SELECT * FROM R1
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT  Essn, Sex as 'SEX OF DEPENDENT', COUNT(Dependent_name) as 'COUNT OF DEPENDENTS'
    from DEPENDENT
    group by Essn, Sex
    order by Essn)TT
where R1.Ssn = Essn;
```

But this gives me 2 ssn columns, when I only want one. How do I need to change my query?

Answer (score 0):

In this piece of your code:

```
    SELECT * FROM R1 
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT Essn, Sex as 'SEX OF DEPENDENT', COUNT(Dependent_name) as 'COUNT OF DEPENDENTS' 
    from DEPENDENT group by Essn, Sex order by Essn)TT 
    where R1.Ssn = Essn;
```

You have select both SSN from R1 (select * from R1) and Essn from the cross join TT.. you need to only select one if you want to see only one.

Try selecting all from R1 and exactly what you want from the cross join TT:

```
    SELECT R1.*,TT.`SEX OF DEPENDENT`, TT.`COUNT OF DEPENDENTS` 
    FROM R1 CROSS JOIN ( SELECT Essn, Sex as 'SEX OF DEPENDENT', COUNT(Dependent_name) as 'COUNT OF DEPENDENTS' 
    from DEPENDENT group by Essn, Sex order by Essn )TT 
    on R1.Ssn = Essn
```

Also consider your naming conventions in your join it makes it more difficult to select TT.`SEX OF DEPENDENT` instead of TT.Sex